# Sinatra {"Content-Type"=>nil} - form response

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra, erb

I've tried thoroughly researching the answer to this but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. I'm a baby coder (still learning) and am building a super basic application. The form is properly displaying the request parameters, but I can't get it to return a response. Although no errors, I do see in the console `{"Content-Type"=>nil}`

Here is my repo: https://github.com/mirandashort/borkapp

For bork_function, I understand it can be simplified with an array. This was just something I created doing *Try Ruby the Hard Way* so I'm just recycling it. As for my code, I'm unsure if the problem lies in `bork_form.rb`, either .erb, or both.

I appreciate any insight!

Comment: this isn't right: `redirect '/bork/:doggo_type/'` you would probably want to interpolate the string: `redirect '/bork/#{doggo_type}'`. Also, not sure why you are redirecting before returning erb. You should do one or the other.

Comment: thank you! as i said, super baby coder. there is not much documentation on sinatra. as for early redirect, i might have just left it on accident

Comment: sinatra has a lot of info in their documentation page: http://www.sinatrarb.com/documentation.html .. so, did that solve your issue?

Comment: Not entirely, but it did at least help me move in the right direction! And yes, I’ve been using that as my guide, but have gotten stuck, which is why I’ve ended up here :)